# Writing SAML2 claim aware asp.net application

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I have a web application (.Net 4.0) that uses WIF and ADFS for SignON. In ADFS my application is configured  as WS-Fed protocol / SAML 1 Token relying party.  Now I have requirement to allow my-application to accept redirect from client application using SAML 2 token.

Based on on-line resources most likely I will have to perform steps
1. Set ADFS trust between both Organizations
2. Switch my-Application Relying party trust from WS-Fed to WS-SSO. 
3. Write Assumer Assertion Service (new page in my application) to accept SAML token

Question
1. Are above steps enough? What else I have to do?
2. Is it required to change my application to use WS-SSO?  Can ADFS be configured to receive SAML2 from client but send SAML1 to my application? If so how can this be achieved?
3. Since WIF does not work with SAML-P what how can I make my application accept SAML 2 token?

Will appreciate any sample / reference / solution to above requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your own Assertion Consumer Service for accepting tokens. Use an existing component/library. There are commercial options available, as well as open source. I maintain [Kentor.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) which is an SP implementation for ASP.NET (requires .NET 4.5).

Comment: Thanks for directing me to Kentor.AuthServices.  I am trying to replace WIF with KenAuthService(with ADFS ).  So far I have installed KenAuthService and Kentor.AuthServices.HttpModule NuGet pkgs.For web.config changes I have used Micsoft.IdentityModel consfig settings as guideline for <Kentor.AuthServices> values. I am getting  '401 access denied due to invalid credentials'.  I don't even get prompted for adfs-login page.  Could this be related to <signingCertificate> being incorrect?  If yes. what is this certificate -  Adfs Service communication cert or Adfs Token signing cert?    Thanks.

Comment: It's the certificate used to sign the assertions/tokens that should be configured with AuthServices.